# How do I replace multiple SQL tables without breaking unknown dependencies?

Tags: sql-server, ddl

I'm not sure if this is possible, and I've found nothing short of "start over with the database" so far:

**Here's what I currently have:**

A set of 10 tables that, when converted from a "quote" into a "policy," essentially copy their data from one table to another. These tables have multiple entities (reports, software, other database items, dynamically-generated) dependent on them.

[image: Current Situation Sample]

**What I WANT to do:**

Create a new table schema that is truly relational (Of these 20 tables, I could drop about 15), but in a way that the pre-existing tables "appear" to exist as they are to anything that depends on them.

[image: What I want]

In the second image, I want anything that is expecting the first image to get it, but behind that is actually the more standardized relational model.

**I've considered:**

1. Create the new tables, then set up triggers to move the data as needed. I'm not liking this solution as it seems error-prone at best.
2. Leave the tables as-is, and slowly move all dependencies into functions or stored procedures until I'm reasonably sure the majority of dependencies have been identified. Then switch to the new schema via these new procedures/functions/etc..
3. Build new schema, point what is known to new schema. Build views that mimic the original tables, and re-point queries there as they are discoverd (messy)

We're already having massive performance problems under the current setup and I'm trying to pre-emptively strike and fix this scenario. The biggest concern I have is that these are transactional tables, storing (at present) about 500,000 records each (you can see why getting rid of 2/3 of them is so appealing). Plus the data and quote sets of tables have new records added in all of them whenever a new transaction occurs.

**QUESTION:** *How do I accomplish this switch without making code changes elsewhere? How do I make everything else "think" that the old table schema still exists but use the new schema going forward?*

Comment: So, what is your question here exactly? You haven't asked one.

Comment: How do I create a situation where all dependencies (database and other software) "think" the old setup is still there while actually using the new setup?

Comment: That is not going to be an easy task, if at all. Post the DDL of your tables and then what you've tried already. And explain why you can't change your code but need to change your design. The latter will almost always require the former.

Comment: Unknown dependencies within the DB or in some other application? If the former, backup, restore as a different DB, and get to testing; make that new schema and import the data from the old tables and just go for it. If the latter... get with that app's maintainer(s) and get them on board; backup, restore as a different DB, and get to testing.

Comment: I'd rather do my best to reveal these unknown dependencies. It is not a good sign that you are not the 'host' in your own database... You may use traces, write emails to potential consumers etc. Sorry it is not the answer to you question, but still an opportunity to keep complexity under control

Comment: IMHO It isn't possible to guarantee "no impact" if you change your data model. You can aim to minimize impacts by providing views that mimic the old tables. This way old select queries will still function (but perhaps not quite as efficiently). Updates probably won't work though, unless you are lucky enough that you can define "update-able views" - but I suspect this is very unlikely. So, there will be impacts, all you can aim for is minimizing those.

Comment: Seems you're all in agreement with the internet. The application stack I support is 15-years old and never followed proper SOC to begin with. It's some independent software stack that does not have features like stepping through the code, nor is it very stable (no real try/catch options). I can identify roughly 90% of the access points, but I was hoping to find some creative solution to save time by turning the original tables into a sql equivalent of a "mapping" layer, since there might be some obscure code dependent on this format.